# Conditional sentence with "even if"

Tags: conditionals

What do you make of this sentence? Thanks!

> **Even if a potential customer would never have seriously considered** switching from a PC to a Mac, the company knew that if they could get them into the store, they had a chance of converting them.

Being a non-native speaker, I’d say there’s nothing wrong with the highlighted bit. At the same time, I am aware of conditional sentences rules: only present, past simple or past perfect (and not “would”) are correct after “if”. Does “even” change things? Would the sentence still be right without it?

Comment: Very awkward, bamboozling construction!  Simplify!  "Even if a potential customer had never seriously considered switching from a PC to a Mac, the company knew that they would have a chance of converting them if they could (just) get them into the store."

Comment: *if the gentleman at the back would please silence his phone ...*

Comment: It’s not ungrammatical to use *would* in conditionals.

Comment: The "conditional sentences rules", as cited, are wrong. Who told them to you? What book are they in? Don't trust them about English from now on.

Comment: There can't be any right answer when all you want to know is my opinion. I think your sentence is furry, oblong, and smells like goat cheese. These kind of questions are also off-topic.

Comment: @Dan That rewrite doesn't seem to be equivalent. "had never" is referring to the actual past, "would never" is a continuous hypothetical.

Comment: The conditional rules you learned are incredibly simplified. There are lots of wrong ways to use *would* in conditionals (they teach you those simplified rules in ESL classes to keep you from using *would* in the wrong ways) and a few correct ways. This is one of the correct ways.

Comment: @JohnLawler ... When someone comes here and cites "conditional rules", it is likely something they learned in ESL instruction.  (English as a Second Language).  So it is probably best to send them to ell.stackexchange.com for clarification.

Comment: @Barmar - fair enough.  I suppose, as originally presented, the (extraordinary) potential of the company to sway the customer is implied (they would never have considered switching UNTIL the company came along).  My version ignores this.  It's a pretty 'nice' point though, and when the OP asked 'what do you make of this...' the version I offer seemed to me to be the obvious intent of the original (and a great deal easier to understand).

Comment: This is a duplicate. You can use *would* in the first clause of a conditional only if it means "willing to", which it kind of does in your sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I answer your question NOT as a grammarian but as a close reader.

Here's a protracted description of a possible scenario:

> Pick a customer. Any customer. Make sure the customer would never under ***normal*** circumstances consider switching from a PC to a Mac. Get that person to step into a Mac store. Have that person talk to a Mac employee. Said employee engages the person in a conversation, the purpose of which is to convince/persuade that person to switch from PC to Mac. The employee may succeed or not, but from the company's perspective at least they have been given a chance to do so, even though the person, normally, would neither consider switching nor be willing to step into a Mac store.

Whereas my protracted description of the scenario takes over 100 words, your highlighted sentence manages to consolidate all the information contained in my description in just 37 words:

> Even if a potential customer would never have seriously considered switching from a PC to a Mac, the company knew that if they could get them into the store, they had a chance of converting them.

Big difference, yes? And while there are other ways to word the sentence, such as the way your first commenter suggested, both ways summarize the scenario quite well. And you know what? They both contain 37 words!